# pandas aggregate column doesnt exist?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Currently i have a dataframe that i am preforming a group by on with aggregate functions. these are the functions

```
            aggregation_functions = {
            '12_months': 'sum',
            '24_months': 'sum',
            '36_months': 'sum',
            'number_36_months': 'sum'
            }
```

when i do the group by it is dropping an ID column that is classed as a "nuisance"

but when i add the aggregate function for this ID column im getting the error:

```
[ERROR] 03/25/2022 12:24:44 PM - Column(s) ['id'] do not exist
```

this is the aggregation im trying to add and this is the group by

```
'id': 'nunique'
final_df = df.groupby(['buy_country', 'buy_activity', 'vd_country', 'vd_activity'], as_index=False).aggregate(aggregation_functions)
```

the column does exist in the data frame df

does anyone know why it thinks the column doesnt exist or how to get the aggregate function for this column to work ?

example of the data:

| id | buy_country | buy_activity | vd_country | vd_activity | number_of_buyers | 36_months | 24_months | 12_months | number_36_months |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 000002 | GB | Not Matched | GB | Not Matched | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 000002 | GB | Not Matched | GB | Not Matched | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 4 |
| 000002 | GB | Not Matched | GB | Not Matched | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 |
| 000002 | GB | Not Matched | GB | Not Matched | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

Comment: Please can you provide the output of `print(df.head(5))`

Comment: @Corralien the table looks fine in the preview but then prints horribly sorry

Comment: managed to fix the table was a spacing issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that id is a column and not an index?

You could try resetting the index of your DataFrame before you groupby:

```
df = df.reset_index()
final_df = df.groupby(['buy_country', 'buy_activity', 'vd_country', 'vd_activity'], as_index=False).aggregate(aggregation_functions)
```

Comment: it was used in as an index in a join before the group by thank you